# Understanding convlstm1d input and kernel size

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to use keras [convlstm1d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM1D) layer for time series prediction deep model with week-based time data.

For each sample, I have weekly purchase information. I want to use conv window of size 4 (monthly standard) to put into the LSTM layer.

Originally, I thought the same input size as using the normal LSTM would be OK for the convlstm1d layer. I expected the layer to automatically apply length 4 filter to (52,1) data. However, I noticed that it was expecting ndim=4.

```
gmv_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (52,1), name="gmv", dtype=np.float32)
rnn_layers = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D(filters=6,kernel_size=4,strides=4,
                                  use_bias=True, activation="relu", dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1),
])
gmv_output = rnn_layers(gmv_input)
```

Therefore, I changed the code to:

```
gmv_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (int(len(GMV_WEEKLY_FEATURES)/4),4,1), name="gmv", dtype=np.float32)
rnn_layers = tf.keras.Sequential([
                    tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D(filters=6,kernel_size=4,strides=4,use_bias=True, activation="relu", 
                                                               dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1),
                    tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
            ])
gmv_output = rnn_layers(gmv_input)
```

This is working, but I am not sure this is the result that I want. I have changed the input size from (N, 52, 1) to (N, 13, 4, 1). Why does the input have to be dim=4 when it is only applying conv1d window?